# "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main".

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I keep getting this error when i try to run this code "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main". Can anyone help me out? Here is my code. Also i have to use a buffered reader to get it to read input, but i cant figure out how to implement that into what i already have. Any help would be awesome!

import java.util.Arrays;

```
    public class StatPackage {

    private int i, numScores, place;
    private double sum, mean, median, sumOfSquares, variance, stdDev;
    private double [] inputs;
    private double [] reducedArray;
    private int [] histogramArray;
    private final int MAX = 500;


    //constructor
    public StatPackage(){
        inputs = new double[MAX]; //creates array
        numScores = 0; // count is 0
        histogramArray = new int[MAX];

    }


    public void Histogram(){
        //histogramArray = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, MAX);

        for (i = 0; i < numScores; i++){ 

            //place = (int)(inputs[i]/10);

            if (inputs[i] > 0 && inputs[i] <= 10){ histogramArray[0]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 10 && inputs[i] <= 20){ histogramArray[1]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 20 && inputs[i] <= 30){ histogramArray[2]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 30 && inputs[i] <= 40){ histogramArray[3]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 40 && inputs[i] <= 50){ histogramArray[4]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 50 && inputs[i] <= 60){ histogramArray[5]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 60 && inputs[i] <= 70){ histogramArray[6]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 70 && inputs[i] <= 80){ histogramArray[7]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 80 && inputs[i] <= 90){ histogramArray[8]+=1;}
            if (inputs[i] > 90 && inputs[i] <= 100){ histogramArray[9]+=1;}

        }
        System.out.print(" 1 - 10  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[0]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("11 - 20  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[1]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("21 - 30  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[2]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("31 - 40  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[3]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("41 - 50  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[4]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("51 - 60  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[5]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("61 - 70  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[6]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("71 - 80  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[7]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("81 - 90  | ");
        for (i = 0; i < (histogramArray[8]/5); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("91 - 100 | ");
        for (i = 0; i < ((histogramArray[9]/5) + (histogramArray[10]/5)); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
    //go through each value of reducedArray, find out what numbers it is between, and increment array value by 1. 
// so if the test score is 35, increment reducedArray[3] by 1. then, divide each array index by 5, print that number of stars. 



    //insert scores into inputs array
    public void insert (double val){
        if (numScores < MAX){
            inputs[numScores] = val;
            numScores++;
            reducedArray = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, numScores);
        }
    }

     double Mean() {
        for (i = 0; i < numScores; i++){
            sum += reducedArray[i];
        }   
        mean = (sum/numScores);
        return mean;            
    }

     double Median(){
        Arrays.sort(reducedArray);
        double num1 = reducedArray[(numScores/2)];
        double num2 = reducedArray[((numScores/2)-1)];

        if (numScores % 2 == 0){
            median = ((num1 + num2)/2);
        }
        if (numScores % 2 != 0){
            median = reducedArray[(numScores/2)];       
        }
        return median;
    }

     double Variance(){

        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
            sumOfSquares += (inputs[i]*inputs[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
            sum = sum + inputs[i];
        }
        variance = ((sumOfSquares/numScores) - (sum * sum)/(numScores * numScores));
        return variance;
    }

     double StdDev (double varianceinput){
        stdDev = Math.sqrt(varianceinput);
        return stdDev;
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: What line are you getting the exception?

Comment: I run the code in a unix terminal by doing [java Lab5]. It compiles no problem. @JPMoresmau

Comment: As soon at i try and run the code i get that error. @ArachnidHivemind

Comment: Where is your main method? You need that to run.

Comment: if you launch java Lab5, then it's the Lab5 class that is ran. What's Lab5.java?

Comment: Thats what i need help with, implementing a buffered reader into this code. Should the main method be StatPackage? @ArachnidHivemind

Comment: Have you written in java before? I'm confused how you even started writing this without having an idea on how it starts

Comment: That is my bad, thats from a different project. To run this i do [java StatPackage] @JPMoresmau

Comment: Im very new to java, my professor helped me write this but told me to figure out how to implement the buffered reader method. @ArachnidHivemind

Comment: you're missing `private static void main {...}` in your code. your code has no idea on where to start implement this and then use your other code in that method

Comment: I implemented that and its printing my full histogram. No i just need it to take inputs.  @ArachnidHivemind

Comment: Ok well it looks like David's answer has you going in the right spot. I'd look up some tutorials on input,loops and conditionals to try to write the rest of your code

Comment: if you accept an answer please [label it appropriately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). :)

Comment: That is only part of the answer, I still need to know how to get the program to take input. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't have a main method. As a first step, try adding something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StatPackage statPackage = new StatPackage();
    statPackage.Histogram();
  }
```

The main method is Java's entry point. Every executable java program needs one.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented that and it compiled. Now i just have to get it to take input.

Answer (score 0):

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:***
firstly check your class name and saved file name are same?
not equal these two names you can get above error.
remember these names are case sensitive.
eg:- saved file name-**t**est.java
     class name: **T**est.java (in textpad)
then you can get above error.